# Routing for Symfony2 TWIG templates with AJAX

Tags: ajax, symfony

I have been struggling with this for a couple days and have yet to find any real solutions online yet. I have a form that allows users to enter their email, then after they enter it fades out and is replaced by another form. I am using ajax to submit data from a form to a symfony2 controller, which stories it in the database and sends a response. However, the response ends up just sending me to a blank page with the response data displayed, instead keeping me on the same page and just fading the boxes as needed. I think my issue is with how I have the controller actions set up and the routing files.

**EDIT**

Well now the issue is that when I click on the submit button nothing happens. Nothing is sent to the controller, so nothing is being stored and no response is being given. What I changed was based on the answer by @PaulPro, appending the

```
<script> $('#emailForm').submit(submitForm); </script>
```

to the end of the html page. Thanks in advance for any help and insight!

The controller has 2 relevant actions, the one that renders the TWIG Template with the form, and the one that handles the ajax form submission and returns the response.

```
public function emailAction()
{
    return $this->render('Bundle:email.html.twig');
}

public function submitEmailAction()
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()-> getEntityManager();

    $email = new Email();

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $emailVar = $request->request->get('emailSignup');

    $email -> setEmail($emailVar);

    $em->persist($email);
    $em->flush();

    $return=array("responseCode"=>200);
    $return = json_encode($return);

    return new Response($return, 200, array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));

}
```

This is the routing for those actions, most likely the culprit of it all:

```
Bundle_email:
pattern:  /email
defaults: { _controller: Bundle:email }
requirements:
    _method:  GET

Bundle_submitEmail:
pattern:  /submitEmail
defaults: { _controller: Bundle:submitEmail }
requirements:
    _method:  POST
```

And then here is the email.html.twig template and ajax script:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="{{asset('css/styles.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function submitForm(){
    var emailForm = $(this);
    var path = "{{path('Bundle_submitEmail')}}"

    $.ajax ( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: $("#emailForm").attr("action"),
        emailSignup: $("#emailId").val(), 
        success: function(data){

        if(data.responseCode==200 ){
            $('.email-signup-form').fadeOut();          
            $('.share-form').delay(500).fadeIn();
        }
        }

      });

 return false;
 }</script>
</head>

<body>
      <form id="emailForm" action="{{path('Bundle_submitEmail')}}" method="POST" class="email-signup-form">
        <input type="email" placeholder="e-mail address" name="emailSignup" id="emailId" required="true"/>
<input type="submit" value="Go">
      </form>
      <form class="share-form">

      </form>
<script> $('#emailForm').submit(submitForm); </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't ever call `submitForm` (the function that tells the browser to use AJAX rather than a full page load). Just add a script at the end of your body that looks like:

```
<script>
    $('#emailForm').submit(submitForm);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Although now when I click on the submit button nothing is happening at all, so I guess I need to take another look at my ajax code.

Comment: @BrianHunter You're welcome. Have your tried checking the Javascript console for errors?

Comment: Ok they error isn't showing well here but its a 500 internal server error and it points to lines 5 and 6 of the jquery and then the lien of my code with the url, perhaps it doesn't like the symfony formatting or path creation. Not sure

Comment: @BrianHunter Could be caused by a PHP error. The next thing to check should be your server-side error logs. Are you the server administrator? Do you know what Operating System and Web Server you are running?

Comment: Ok so the error is actually showing for the $.ajax(   function. I have access to the server but I know it submits fine when I am not using the ajax call so I'm not sure if that would be the issue. I'll look into the server error logs though

Comment: The full error is 500 internal server error
send
x.extend.ajax
submitForm
x.event.dispatch
v.handle

Comment: @BrianHunter The 500 is coming from your server. So the error is there, but it could be caused by your ajax request. The `emailSignup` part looks funny as normally you put parameters in a `data` section for Ajax

Comment: Maybe try `data: {emailSignup: $("#emailId").val() },`

Comment: Hey that did the trick! Thanks a lot Paul I really appreciate it!